# Negative binomial regression SPSS - Quantity vs Distance

Tags: regression, spss

I have quite a simple dataset of quantities of litter found in a national park located on an island. For each data point I have corresponding GPS coordinates, and I've derived the distance of each point to the shore. My aim: observe if the quantities of litter increase or decrease with the distance to shore. I'm assuming that quantities of litter will increase with a decrease in distance, as litter is commonly found on beaches etc.

Quantities of litter are counts, i.e. non-parametric. Additionally I've tested the data to see if it follows a Poisson model and it does not (p-value <0.05), and I have a larger variance than the mean for each variable (quantity and distance) seemingly overdispersed. Therefore, I went on using a negbin regression, with an output as follows:
[image]

Omnibus test is highly significant (p=0.000). I was just slightly puzzled on the parameter estimates, and generally hoping that this approach makes sense. Any input much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreting the parameter estimates requires knowing the link function specified, which would be a log link if you specified your model as a negative binomial with log link on the Type of Model tab, but could be something else if you specified a custom model using a negative binomial distribution with another link (which could be identity, negative binomial, or power, instead).

If it's a log link, then for a distance of 0 (at the shore), you predict exp(2,636) for the count, or about 13,957. For a given distance from the shore, multiply the distance by -,042 and add that to the 2,636 value, then take the exponential function to the resulting power. So for every unit away from the shore you move, the log of the prediction decreases by ,042, and the prediction is multiplied by about ,959. One unit away, you predict about 13,383 for the count, two units away, about 12,833, etc. So the results are in general accord with your hypothesis. Different specific calculations would be required if you used a different link function.